# Edit PDF programatically in c# (Non-Fillable PDF)

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation, itext, acrofields

**Is it possible to Edit PDF that is not Forms Fillable  in C#**

### Details :

1. An Existing PDF contains Images, Tables filled with Data and Text.
2. Already tried **itextsharp** but couldn't able to identify any ***AcroFields to Manipulate the data***.
3. When tried to OCR using Nitro PDF, got Error : OCR cannot be done, since this page contains Editable / Searchable Contents

[image: ***Sample_Text Replace using ASPOSE***]... *This is the output from ASPOSE Text Replacement ... tried to Replace Word **April** with **June***

### Requirement :

Have to edit the Text and Data Filled in Tables Programatically and Save it.

Comment: I did something similar, as it is now it only works with text, but if you provide an example PDF i could try to tweak it a bit if needed, the idea is getting words/sentences with locations then using blank rectangles to erase these words/sentences, then we could add different text (same size) over those locations. This approach uses the OverContent layer. I added a link to my project (VB.NET 2010) in a thread in iTextSharp FAQs under the name "how to highlight a text or word in a pdf file using iTextsharp?". If something like this would help just show an example PDF and i'll see what i can do.

Answer (score 0):

If a commercial library is an option for you, you could try with [Amyuni PDF Creator .Net](http://www.amyuni.com/en/developer/pdfcreator/features.html). The method [GetObjectsInRectangle](http://amyuni.com/WebHelp/Amyuni_PDF_Creator_for_NET/Amyuni_PDFCreator_IacDocument/Methods/GetObjectsInRectangle_Method.htm) will allow you to enumerate all the elements in the specified rectangle, you can then inspect the object type, and if it is a text object and it contains the text that you want you can replace it by assigning a new value to the Text attribute. Be aware that the rest of the text on your page will not be re-adjusted, so the new text must fit in the same space that the previous text was taking.